# Legends in Simulink's scope are gray, but the lines have proper colors

Tags: matlab, simulink

[image: image description]

Suddenly, the legend colors started showing all gray. That's not very useful. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Define suddenly. Right after your last cigarette? ;) Seriously, we can't tell you what is wrong if you don't give us anything to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Unexpectedly. Without any known cause or any known change to the system that could be the cause. In other words, I changed no settings ran matlab and this is what I saw. I restarted matlab now because it crashed again, maybe it will become fixed.

Comment: This is more question aimed to those that also encountered the problem than those who would try to reproduce it. It's obviously another simulink bug. But even bug can sometimes be "worked around".

Comment: So you can reproduce it everytime you run the code? Can you reduce your model that way, that you can share it with us? And which Matlab version are you using on which OS? What happens if you change the color of graphs afterwards in the scope window? Does the legend get colored again?

Comment: I played around, they remained gray. After restart it was fixed.